# Fitting, Pareto-Levy Stable distributions and hist() function

Tags: r, data-fitting

I'm trying to proof that my log_returns distribution [(Here the histogram)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4nB6.png) is correctly fitted by a Pareto-Levy Stable Distribution. I started using `fitdistr(log_returnsSP500,"normal")` to estimate my parameters with MASS:

```
   mean            sd     

 0.0002738807   0.0113987124 
(0.0001835401) (0.0001297825)
```

Then, i estimated the stable distribution parameters in this way:

```
stableFit(log_returnsSP500,alpha=1.75,beta=0,gamma=1,delta=0,type=c("mle"),
      doplot=TRUE)

Title:
 Stable Parameter Estimation

 Call:
.mleStableFit(x = x, alpha = Alpha, beta = Beta, gamma = Gamma, 
delta = Delta, doplot = doplot, control = control, trace = trace,
title = title, description = description)

Model:
 Stable Distribution

Estimated Parameter(s):
    alpha          beta         gamma         delta 
 1.6211874757 -0.1077639387  0.0057637299  0.0006406242
```

Now, i want to verify the grade of proximity superimposing the density function on my histogram. Surely it will result that Pareto-Stable Distribution fits much better than normal, but i don't know how to proof it. Anyone could help me with codes? Thanks.